# Docker CLI not found after installing Docker Desktop on M1 Mac

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm running Docker Desktop on my M1 Mac(Sonoma), but when I try to use the docker CLI in the terminal, I get the error "docker: command not found."

I've checked and Docker Desktop is definitely running. How can I get the docker commands to work in my terminal?

I should be able to run docker commands from terminal